# Universal links - Unregistered XPC Activity: com.apple.SharedWebCredentials.recheck

Tags: ios11, ios-universal-links

I am trying to implement the universal link for my domain in Xcode9. The teamID and bundle identifier for debug/inhouse are different from release build. And I am testing the debug version on real device. Kinda stuck here. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

I have uploaded the unsigned apple-app-site-association file to myDomain/.well-known/ folder, and the type is application/json. The file could be returned when using curl -v myDomain/.well-known/AASA as below:

```
{
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "TeamID.BundleIdentifier"
        ]
    },
    "applnks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "TeamID.BundleIdentifier",
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In myDomain server header, I have added the following line

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=App_Store_ID">
```

The associate domain was also turned on and added applinks:myDomain under the capabilities in Xcode

Following code has been added to appDelegate:

```
/* universal links */
    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Swift.Void) -> Bool {
        // 1
        NSLog("Continue User Activity called: ")
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
            let webURL = userActivity.webpageURL!

            if !present(URL: webURL as NSURL) {
                application.openURL(webURL)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Deleted my App and safari websiteData on iPhone7. Run the project on my phone, following is the console log:

```
Oct 13 16:13:36 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Added service 'applinks', appID 'TEAMID.BundleIdentifier', domain 'myDomain'
Oct 13 16:13:36 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Started request for domain 'myDomain', URL 'https://myDomain/.well-known/apple-app-site-association'
Oct 13 16:13:36 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Added service 'activitycontinuation', appID 'TEAMID.BundleIdentifier', domain 'myDomain'
Oct 13 16:13:36 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Skipping request for domain 'myDomain' when already outstanding
Oct 13 16:13:36 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Added service 'webcredentials', appID 'TEAMID.BundleIdentifier', domain 'myDomain'
Oct 13 16:13:36 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Skipping request for domain 'myDomain' when already outstanding
Oct 13 16:13:36 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC Enabling TLS [20:0x102b25a80]
Oct 13 16:13:36 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Start [20:0x102b25a80]
Oct 13 16:13:36 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: Task <A5234022-0A81-4656-B774-68E7F7FD6441>.<1> setting up Connection 20
Oct 13 16:13:37 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [20:0x102b25a80]: 1, Pending(0)
Oct 13 16:13:37 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [20:0x102b25a80]: 2, Pending(0)
Oct 13 16:13:37 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [20:0x102b25a80]: 11, Pending(0)
Oct 13 16:13:37 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [20:0x102b25a80]: 12, Pending(0)
Oct 13 16:13:37 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [20:0x102b25a80]: 14, Pending(0)
Oct 13 16:13:38 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TLS Trust Result [20:0x102b25a80]: 0
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [20:0x102b25a80]: 20, Pending(0)
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Connected [20:0x102b25a80]: Err(16)
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Event [20:0x102b25a80]: 1
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Event [20:0x102b25a80]: 8
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TLS Handshake Complete [20:0x102b25a80]
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: Task <A5234022-0A81-4656-B774-68E7F7FD6441>.<1> now using Connection 20
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: Task <A5234022-0A81-4656-B774-68E7F7FD6441>.<1> sent request, body N
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: Task <A5234022-0A81-4656-B774-68E7F7FD6441>.<1> received response, status 200 content K
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: Task <A5234022-0A81-4656-B774-68E7F7FD6441>.<1> response ended
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Completing request for 'https://myDomain/.well-known/apple-app-site-association', status 0/0x0 noErr
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Updated app ID 'TEAMID.BundleIdentifier', domain 'myDomain', flags 0x0 < > -> 0x4 < SiteDenied > on check
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Updated app ID 'TEAMID.BundleIdentifier', domain 'myDomain', flags 0x0 < > -> 0x4 < SiteDenied > on check
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Updated app ID 'TEAMID.BundleIdentifier', domain 'myDomain', flags 0x0 < > -> 0x2 < SiteApproved > on check
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Closing URL session
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Retry needed for 'de.m.yelp.ch' success in 4d 23h 13m 39s
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CoreUtils)[207] <Notice>: Scheduling recheck in 4d 23h 13m 48s
Oct 13 16:13:39 UserEventAgent(com.apple.cts)[23] <Notice>: Unregistered XPC Activity: com.apple.SharedWebCredentials.recheck
Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Cancel [20:0x102b25a80]
```

My questions are:
1. I added https://myDomain in notes, long press the url, it shows open link but no open in app option. what should I do to bring up the "open in app" option when long pressing?

2. Long press the url, choose open, it opens in safari. The smart banner in safari only points to apple store, as if safari never knows that the debug version has already installed on the phone. How can safari knows that debug version is installed hence it should show "open" in the smart banner?
3. when clicking on the url, universal Link method in appDelegate wasn't called. Any settings not set correctly?
4. There's an error in following line in the device console log.  Also from the device console log, can we conclude that requesting apple-app-site-association file succeeded?

   Oct 13 16:13:39 swcd(CFNetwork)[207] : TIC TCP Conn Connected [20:0x102b25a80]: Err(16)

Thanks very much.

Comment: What is your question? Your Universal Links does not work?
Not sure you need WellKnown stuff. See examples SIGNED AASA http://facebook.com/apple-app-site-association ; UNSIGNED AASA https://www.google.com/apple-app-site-association

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov, sorry just added the questions.

Comment: Couple suggestions: Try this tool with your URL https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/ . Try to reinstall the App and increase version number of the App as AASA sometimes stale when version # is not increased. Ensure your TeamID is the same as AppPrefixID. You need AppPrefixID in AASA.

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov thanks. the validation tool didn't work well last week, just tried that tool again, looks like something wrong at the sever side.

Comment: for anyone who might also face the same issue, after updating the AASA file at the sever side, the universal link worked again. Even thou the domain didn't  pass the app search-validation-tool, it did pass via [link](http://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/)

Comment: you have a typo in your association file,  you have _applnks_ instead of _applinks_

Comment: @paulatstepupsoftware, thanks for the help.